# Uniqueness of a Decomposition of a finitely generated torsion module over a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules, principal-ideal-domains

Let $M$ be a finitely generated torsion $R$-module. Show that we can write $M \cong R/(a_1) \oplus ... \oplus R/(a_n)$ such that $a_1 | a_2 | ... | a_n$. Show that $a_1,...,a_n$ are uniquely determined up to a unit

With the help of Lukas Heger, I was able to show that $M$ has such a decomposition. Now I am working on the uniqueness part. Here is an argument from Lukas Heger which I am having trouble following:

> Okay so maybe an induction argument can be made to work.
> We want to prove that if $M=R/(a_1) \oplus \dots R/(a_n) \cong N=R/(b_1) \oplus \dots R/(b_m)$ with $a_1 \mid a_2 \mid \dots$ and $b_1 \mid b_2 \mid \dots$, then $n=m$ and $a_i=b_i$ up to units.
> We induct on the number of prime factors (with multiplicity) of $\mathrm{Ann}_R(M)$.
> As a base case if $\mathrm{Ann}_R(M)=(p)$ is prime, then $M$ is a vector space over $M/(p)$ and so we get that $M \cong (R/(p))^n$ where $n=\mathrm{dim}_{R/(p)}(M)$. Clearly this $n$ is unique.
> Now the inductive step: let $p$ be any prime divisor of $\mathrm{Ann}_R(M)=(a)$.
> Now consider $pM$. If $p \nmid a_i$, then $p R/(a_i)=R/(a_i)$. If $a_i=a'_ip$, then $p R/(a_i) \cong R/(a'_i)$. Define $a'_i=a_i$ if $p \nmid a_i$ and $a'_i=a_i/p$ if $p \mid a_i$. Do the same thing for the $b_i$s.
> So from $M \cong N$, we get
> $pM \cong pN$:
> $R/(a'_1) \oplus \dots \oplus R/(a'_n) \cong R/(b'_1) \oplus \dots \oplus R/(b'_m)$
> The inductive step gives $n=m$ and $a'_i=b'_i$
> We can also consider $M/pM$ and $N/pN$ which are vector spaces over $R/(p)$, the dimension will be the number of $a_i$ that are divisible by $p$.
> Putting these informations together we can reconstruct $a_i$ from $a'_i$ and $b_i$ from $b'_i$ since we know at which point we need to multiply with $p$

For the base case, I have a few questions. Why does $\dim_{R/(p)} (M) = n$ (the number of $a_i$'s in $M$'s decomposition), and why does uniqueness of the dimension imply that $a_i$ and $b_i$ differ by a unit? If it's the case that $\dim_{R/(p)}(M) = n$, then I can see why $m=n$, but I don't see why $a_i$ and $b_i$ differ by a unit.

For the inductive part, presumably $p$ is a divisor of $a$, which we're assuming has $\ell+1$ primes in its factorization. Is this right? Also, the notation $pR/(a_i)$ means $\{pr + (a_i) \mid r \in R \}$, and $p R/(a_i) \cong R/(a'_i)$ is an isomorphism of $R$-modules with the isomorphism given by $pr + (a_i) \mapsto r + (a_i')$?

Also, the inductive step can be invoked because $Ann_{R}(pM) = (\frac{a}{p})$ and $\frac{a}{p}$ has $\ell$ prime factors?

Also, when he says,

> We can also consider $M/pM$ and $N/pN$ which are vector spaces over $R/(p)$, the dimension will be the number of $a_i$ that are divisible by $p$.

Is this just an alternative way of showing $n=m$, or is it crucial to the proof? I ask because I am unable to establish it.

Finally, from what I understand,

> Putting these informations together we can reconstruct $a_i$ from $a'_i$ and $b_i$ from $b_i'$ since we know at which point we need to multiply with $p$.

encompasses several cases. We could have $a_i = a_i'$ and $b_i = b_i', or $a_i = a_i'p and $b_i = b_i'$, etc. The only case which I am unable to verify is when, without loss of generality, $a_i = a_i'p$ and $b_i = b_i'$. From the induction step, we know that $a_i'$ and $b_i'$ differ by a unit; that is, $a_i' = ub_i'$ for some unit $u \in R$. Multiplying both sides by $p$, $a_i' p = u pb_i'$ or $a_i = up b_i$ (after substitution)...But I don't see how go from this to saying that $a_i$ and $b_i$ differ by a unit.

As of now, I think these are the only parts I don't understand. I could use some help.

Comment: The information from $M/pM$ and $N/pN$ is crucial to the proof. It tells you how to get $a_i$ and $b_i$ from $a'_i$ and $b'_i$: if $l$ is the dimension of $M/pM$ over $R/(p)$, then you need to multiply the last $l$ $a'_i$ by $p$ and the same for $b'_i$

Comment: This is because as I said, this dimension is the number of $a_i$ (and $b_i$) divisible by $p$. But as $a_i \mid a_{i+1}$ for all $i$, if some $a_i$ is divisible by $p$, then so are the $a_i$s after it.

Comment: there's also a sublety in proving $n=m$ that I didn't touch on in the proof sketch: you could have $a_1=p$ in which case $pM$ has less terms in the sum than $M$. But you can still reconstruct $n$ from the number of terms in $pM$ via the information about the dimension of $M/pM$

Comment: For the base case: if $\mathrm{Ann}(M)=(p)$ is prime, then all $a_i$s are equal to $p$ (up to a unit)